# RLMException in XCTest unit tests with Realm database

Tags: ios, unit-testing, realm, xctest

I've got a series of individual `XCTest` unit tests that each run a JSON parsing function - as part of the parsing, any instances of a Realm object class that exist are deleted, before they are recreated based on the JSON that is being handled.

In the `setup()` function of each test class, the Realm instance is being setup with this:

```
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.inMemoryIdentifier = NSUUID().UUIDString

    do {
        realm = try Realm()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        // handle error
        fatalError("Unable to establish Realm stack: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    // Clear Realm of everything
    try! realm.write {
        realm.deleteAll()
    }
```

As I understand things, this should create a completely unique and empty Realm instance for each test.

Running each test class individually works fine, but when run as part of the full test suite a random selection of tests fail with an error:

`caught "RLMException", "Object has been deleted or invalidated."`

I assume this is because there's a race condition somewhere when all the test classes are run simultaneously as part of the test target. That raises three questions:

- is this a race condition, or am I misinterpreting the error?
- is there any way of absolutely enforcing separation of the Realms in each test class to prevent the race conditions?
- is there any way of forcing the test target to run each class synchronously?

**UPDATE** Separating out the clashing test into a separate test target prevents the clash, but that's not really an optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of mutating the default configuration, could you try setting it?

```
var uniqueConfiguration = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration
uniqueConfiguration.inMemoryIdentifier = NSUUID().UUIDString
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = uniqueConfiguration
```

If this works, I'd qualify the current Realm behavior as a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I've rerun the tests using this config, but no change - while all the tests sit in the same target, the errors still occur. Separating them out into two targets means everything works fine,

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation for Realm Swift recommends that each test configure the default Realm to use a unique file (https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#configuring-the-default-realm). This should satisfy your second question, and at the very least prevent errors from unit tests scribbling upon each others' shared state.

Comment: Thanks - that's what the `Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.inMemoryIdentifier = NSUUID().UUIDString`line is doing - each test case runs with a UUID as an identifier, which should guarantee uniqueness. Unfortunately that's not helping here.

Comment: Oops - sorry about that! You're probably better off with JP's suggestion then.